# ADB Shell Input text unicode value gives permission error

Tags: adb

I am running below command on Ubuntu with connected devices

```
adb shell input text "तणणररथ"
```

but it gives me permission denied error and start dumping state of the device

```
sh: resetreason: can't execute: Permission denied
========================================================
== dumpstate: 2018-11-28 03:20:03
========================================================

.......
```

Can you please help me on this?

Answer (score 2):

From this StackOverflow post: [adb shell input unicode character](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14224549/295004) `adb shell input` isn't designed for unicode characters.

The most promising [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18717209/295004) points to a github repo: [ADBKeyBoard](https://github.com/senzhk/ADBKeyBoard) however there is a note that it may not work on Android O / Android P.